# how to install gem without building it

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

I have a gem (ruby-odbc) I need to install on linux box. The gem requires compilation during install and I can't do it on target machine. Is there any way I can copy gem binaries installed on different but almost identical machine skipping compilation?

Comment: You could try. On your local machine find the gem's install directory with: gem which ruby-odbc. Copy that directory over and give it a whirl

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by vendoring the gems with bundler, then distributing that to the linux machines.

Bundler provides a [Bundle Package](http://bundler.io/bundle_package.html).

To lock and cache gems to `./vendor/cache`

```
$ bundle package
```

Then in your deployment you can add the `--local` flag to prevent RubyGems from going to rubygems.org:

```
$ bundle install --local
```

The `./vendor/cache` directory can be stored in your repo, or you can add it as part of your deployment process.